# CKEditor InnerHTML error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor

I have two CKeditor fields that are a part of the form. I have some action buttons on the page, so whenever I click either 'clear' or 'cancel' this function is fired along with other stuff:

```
    CKEDITOR.instances['ed1'].updateElement();
    CKEDITOR.instances['ed1'].setData('');
    CKEDITOR.instances['ed2'].updateElement();
    CKEDITOR.instances['ed2'].setData('');
```

That way I am cleaning the contents of the CKEditor fields. The problem is that if I click 'cancel', then go back to the page and click "clear", Internet Explorer gives an "innerHTML is null or undefined" JS error.

It works fine in other browsers and only happens if I perform the update twice in a row from different buttons. Is there a workaround for that?

CKEditor initialization onReady:

```
 CKEDITOR.replace('ed1', { htmlEncodeOutput: true, width:"700",toolbar: 'Basic'
});

CKEDITOR.replace('ed2', { htmlEncodeOutput: true, width:"700",toolbar: 'Basic'
});
```

I probably should add that I use `.show()` and `.hide()` whenever I use cancel button to hide the form and show other stuff. There's no page reload.

Comment: Could you post some more code? And have you tried using the jquery extension and then doing `$('#ed2').val('');` - http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Developers_Guide/jQuery_Adapter

Comment: Using the jQuery adapter would mean just adding an extra layer and it won't help him to understand the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution to this problem. The reason it was doing that because my clear method was fired using jQuery `bind` function and wasn't placed in the onReady function, so it was binding the events together and giving this error. The solution to this was to use `unbind` first.